# Combo box not populating even though displaymemberpath is not null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have tried setting itemsource to equal the datagrid items source since I 
 only want to display the "un" property once. I have also set the binding property in the xaml for the combo box and returns with the class reference. when debugging it correctly sets the displaymember path but it doesnt show up in the combo box when i run it.

```
 private void dgViewCBIData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           cbi= (CBICalculate)dgViewCBIData.SelectedItem;
            txtName.Text = cbi.Name.ToString();
            txtHeight.Text = cbi.He.ToString();
            txtWeight.Text = cbi.We.ToString();
            cmbUnits.DisplayMemberPath = cbi.Un;  


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DisplayMemberPath` property is supposed to be set a `string` that identifies the name of the property that you want to display in the `ComboBox`.

So if you have a property named `Un` and want to display the value of this one, you should set the `DisplayMemberPath` to the `string` "Un":

```
cmbUnits.DisplayMemberPath = "Un";
```